# Some doubts about the architecture of a very simple Java command line application that have to perform some queries on a DB

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jdbc, architecture

I am pretty new in JDBC and in architecture designe.

I have to implement this simple console application (it is a command line appliation that run into Windows Command Prompt).

My application is composed of a **Main** class containing the **main()** method. This **main()** method receive 2 parameters (inserted by the user when he perform the application) and use these parameters to perform a query on the DB.

So I am following this tutorial: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jdbc/jdbc-sample-code.htm

Ok, so I have done something like this:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

         Properties prop = new Properties();
         InputStream input = null;

         if(args.length != 0) {
            String partitaIVA = args[0];
            String nomePDF = args[1];
         }

         Connection conn = null;
         Statement stmt = null;

         try {
             ....................................................
             ....................................................
             ....................................................

             Class.forName ("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");

             TimeZone timeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("Etc/GMT+2");
             TimeZone.setDefault(timeZone);

             conn = DriverManager.getConnection(prop.getProperty("dburl"), prop.getProperty("dbuser"), prop.getProperty("dbpswd")); // Oracle DB

} catch(SQLException ex) {
             ex.printStackTrace();
         } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();  //To change body of catch statement use File | Settings | File Templates.
         } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();  //To change body of catch statement use File | Settings | File Templates.
         } catch (IOException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();  //To change body of catch statement use File | Settings | File Templates.
         } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();  //To change body of catch statement use File | Settings | File Templates.
         }
    }
}
```

So at this stage I only register the JDBC driver for the Oracle DBMS and then I obtain the connection by this line:

```
conn = DriverManager.getConnection(prop.getProperty("dburl"), prop.getProperty("dbuser"), prop.getProperty("dbpswd")); // Oracle DB
```

It works well and the **Connection** object is correctly obtained.

Ok, looking at the posted tuotorial it show that, after obtained the initialized **Connection** object, he use this connection to create a **Statement** object representin the SQL statment to perform (using a String representing the query), then it perform this SQL statment obtaining a **ResultSet** so finnally he iterate on this **ResultSet** object to extract all the rows representing the result of the performed query.

It is clear for me but I think that put all this stuff in my **Main** class is pretty orrible.

So I am thinking that I can split in the following way:

1. Into the **main()** method of the **Main** class I obtain the connection (as done at this time).
2. Then I creare a **DAO** class in wich I do all the other operations: creation of the **Statement** object and of the relative queries, query execution and extraction of the **ResultSet** values into a collection.

So into the **main()** method first I obtain the connection, then I create my **DAO** object passing to it this connection and so I can perform my queries.

Is it a valid solution from the architectural point of view ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, effectively your main class is your UI layer.  [Multi-Layer Architecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multilayered_architecture) separates data-access out from UI layers.

Now, for a single class "application" I'm not sure I would bother, as the whole point of a multi-layered architecture is to separate concerns, and thus simplify the application.

If you find yourself writing a second interface to this, adding significant business logic, or making more than a single query, then you should definitely contemplate putting some more structure into it.